# How do Vaishnava traditions (other than Madhva) explain this pancharatra verse which affirms the existence of an Eternal hell?

Tags: scripture, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, agamas, pancharatra

The Pancharatra Agama Prakasha Samhita has this verse -

```
शिरमर्मग्रन्थिकूटजलनीरोधनादयः । सन्त्येवाष्टोत्तरशतनरकाः पातकालयाः ॥३९॥

अनित्यनरका एते तामिश्रन्धतामिश्रकौ । **नित्यौ द्वौ नरकौ** तत्र गतायान्ति तमः क्रमाथ् ॥४०॥
```

- **प्रकाशसंहिता - द्वितीयपरिच्छेदः - पञ्चमोऽध्यायः**

The Above Verse lists various hells and directly states that 'Tamisra' And 'AndhaTamisra' are Nitya Narakas (Eternal Hells). While this concept aligns perfectly with the beliefs of the Madhva sampradaya which accepts these as eternal hells, it goes against the concepts of the other Vaishnava schools who do not believe any Hell to be eternal.

So My Question is How do the Vaisnava sects outside those of the Madhva sampradaya interpret this pancharatra verse?

Comment: None of the Vaishnava traditions except Madhva's accept eternal hell.

Comment: @User29449 I know, And that's why I am curious as to how the non-madhva vaishanavs interpret this, since Pancharatras are treated as authority for almost all major vaishnava sect and this verse in particular actually mentions the term 'nitya naraka' which is favoring the madhva position

Comment: It is simply a metaphor. Non-Vaishnavas aren't non-Hindus. They understand the fact of how to interpret metaphors in the context of non-primary texts. If Madhvas literally took backbone texts like Upanishads on literal basis, their own very philosophy would collapse.

Comment: @User29449 Can't be a metaphor in this case. Verse in question lists the eternal and non-eternal hells seperately.

Comment: So what? Upanishads list Shiva and Vishnu separately. Does that mean there are two Brahmans? The words clearly used here signify a metaphor. I can't help with these anymore if you don't wish to.